# Detect what page you are on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to detect what page you are on in JavaScript?

Why I want to know is so that i can detect what page i am on, and then set the style of an element accordingly.

Comment: var fullPath = window.location.pathname;
var whatPage = fullPath.split("/").pop();

Comment: If your on your own site, then location.pathname is probably easiest. if it only returns "/" then your at your home page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`document.URL` will get you the URL of the current page.

To check for a specific page you would use:

```
if ( document.URL.includes("homepage.aspx") ) {
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: Ah thankyou, one mroe question. How would i do it so that if it contains the name of the page, it will perform some action

Comment: Not sure what you mean, where is the name of the page?

Comment: Oh sorry, say for example i have a page called homepage.aspx. How would i do it so that if the url contains homepage.aspx; it will then perform some action

Comment: if ( document.URL.contains("homepage.aspx") ) {

Comment: So you would supply 'homepage.aspx' as the matching criteria?  Can you modify your question above to ask for this additional requirement?

Comment: No problem - if you wouldn't mind marking the question as the answer that would be great.

Comment: And what if you hosting and you want to detect the home page but the page doesn't have a URL, e.g. the URL would be www.mywebsite.com, about would be www.mywebsite.com/about. So the homepage doesn't have a /. So how would you detect the home page then?

Answer (score 2):

Get url of page are you on

```
location.href
```

Or

```
document.URL
```

Set style to element by id:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.border = '1px solid black';
```